# Find a growth rate that creates values adding to a determined total

Tags: excel, math

I am trying to create a forecast tool that shows a smooth growth rate over a determined number of steps while adding up to a determined value.  We have variables tied to certain sales values and want to illustrate different growth patterns.  I am looking for a formula that would help us to determine the values of each individual step.

as an example:  say we wanted to illustrate 100 units sold, starting with sales of 19 units,  over 4 months with an even growth rate we would need to have individual month sales of 19, 23, 27 and 31.  We can find these values with a lot of trial and error, but I am hoping that there is a formula that I could use to automatically calculate the values.

We will have a starting value (current or last month sales), a total amount of sales that we want to illustrate, and a period of time that we want to evaluate -- so all I am missing is a way to determine the change needed between individual values.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This basically is a problem in sequences and series. If the starting sales number is `a`, the difference in sales numbers between consecutive months is `d`, and the number of months is `n`, then the total sales is

```
S = n/2 * [2*a + (n-1) * d]
```

In your example, `a=19`, `n=4`, and `S=100`, with `d` unknown. That equation is easy to solve for `d`, and we get

```
d = 2 * (S - a * n) / (n * (n - 1))
```

There are other ways to write that, of course. If you substitute your example values into that expression, you get `d=4`, so the sales values increase by `4` each month.

Answer (score 1):

For excel you can use this formula:

```
=IF(D1<>"",(D1-1)*($B$1-$B$2*$B$3)/SUMPRODUCT(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,$B$3-1)))+$B$2,"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Excel. 
This is simply a Y=mX+b equation.
Assuming you want a steady growth rate over a time with x periods you can use this formula to determine the slope of your line (growth rate - designated as 'm'). As long as you have your two data points (starting sales value & ending sales value) you can find 'm' using

m   =    (y2-y1)  /  (x2-x1)

That will calculate the slope. Y2 represents your final sales goal. Y1 represents your current sales level. X2 is your number of periods in the period of performance (so how many months are you giving to achieve the goal). X1 = 0 since it represents today which is time period 0.

Once you solve for 'm' this will plug into the formula  y=mX+b. Your 'b' in this scenario will always be equal to your current sales level (this represents the y intercept).

Then all you have to do to calculate the new 'Y' which represents the sales level at any period by plugging in any X value you choose. So if you are in the first month, then x=1. If you are in the second month X=2. The 'm' & 'b' stay the same.

See the Excel template below which serves as a rudimentary model. The yellow boxes can be filled in by the user and the white boxes should be left as formulas.

[image]